# How to remove check digit from barcode39

Tags: javascript, barcode

I am trying to remove the check-digit from my barcode via javascript.

In my current situation the check digit is not needed. [Click here for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5c6p.png)
Our scanners will be scanning pack lists will generated cart numbers from our website.

I literally just need the scanner to be able to only scan 2900 not 2900B.

```
function DrawCode39Barcode(data,
                            checkDigit)
{
  return DrawHTMLBarcode_Code39(data,checkDigit,"yes","in", 0,2,.5,2,"bottom","center","","black","white"); 
}

function DrawHTMLBarcode_Code39(data,
                                 checkDigit,
                                 humanReadable,
                                 units,
                                 minBarWidth,
                                 width,height,
                                 barWidthRatio,
                                 textLocation,
                                 textAlignment,
                                 textStyle,
                                 foreColor,
                                 backColor)
{
  return DrawBarcode_Code39(data,
                            checkDigit,
                            humanReadable,
                            units,
                            minBarWidth,
                            width,height,
                            barWidthRatio,
                            textLocation,
                            textAlignment,
                            textStyle,
                            foreColor,
                            backColor,
                            "html");
}

function DrawBarcode_Code39(data,
                             checkDigit,
                             humanReadable,
                             units,
                             minBarWidth,
                             width,height,
                             barWidthRatio,
                             textLocation,
                             textAlignment,
                             textStyle,
                             foreColor,
                             backColor,
                             mode)
{

  if (foreColor==undefined)
    foreColor="black";
  if (backColor==undefined)
    backColor="white";

  if (textLocation==undefined)
    textLocation="bottom";
  else if (textLocation!="bottom" && textLocation!="top")
    textLocation="bottom";
  if (textAlignment==undefined)
    textAlignment="center";
  else if (textAlignment!="center" && textAlignment!="left" && textAlignment!="right")
    textAlignment="center";
  if (textStyle==undefined)
    textStyle="";
  if (barWidthRatio==undefined)
    barWidthRatio=3;              
  if (height==undefined)
    height=1;
  else if (height<=0 || height >15)
    height=1;
  if (width==undefined)
    width=3;
  else if (width<=0 || width >15)
    width=3;
  if (minBarWidth==undefined)
    minBarWidth=0;
  else if (minBarWidth<0 || minBarWidth >2)
    minBarWidth=0;
  if (units==undefined)
    units="in";
  else if (units!="in" && units !="cm")
    units="in";
  if (humanReadable==undefined)
    humanReadable="yes";
  else if (humanReadable!="yes" && humanReadable !="no")
    humanReadable="yes";

  var encodedData=EncodeCode39(data,checkDigit);    
  var humanReadableText = ConnectCode_Encode_Code39(data,checkDigit);
  var encodedLength = 0;
  var thinLength = 0;
  var thickLength = 0.0;
  var totalLength = 0.0;
  var incrementWidth = 0.0;
  var swing = 1;
  var result="";
  var barWidth=0;
  var thickWidth=0.0;
  var svg;
  if (barWidthRatio >= 2 && barWidthRatio <= 3)
  {
  }
  else
    barWidthRatio = 3;

  for (x = 0; x < encodedData.length; x++)
  {
    if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 't')
    {
      thinLength++;
      encodedLength++;
    }
    else if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 'w')
    {
      thickLength = thickLength + barWidthRatio;
      encodedLength = encodedLength + 3;
    }
  }
  totalLength = totalLength + thinLength + thickLength;

  if (minBarWidth > 0)
  {
    barWidth = minBarWidth.toFixed(2);
    width=barWidth * totalLength;
  }
  else
    barWidth = (width / totalLength).toFixed(2);

  thickWidth = barWidth * 3;
  if (barWidthRatio >= 2 && barWidthRatio <= 3.0)
  {
    thickWidth = barWidth * barWidthRatio;
  }

  if (mode=="html")
  {
    if (textAlignment=='center')
      result='<div style="text-align:center">';
    else if (textAlignment=='left')
      result='<div style="text-align:left;">';
    else if (textAlignment=='right')
      result='<div style="text-align:right;">';

    var humanSpan="";
    if (humanReadable=='yes' && textLocation=='top')
    {
      if (textStyle=='')
        humanSpan='<span style="font-family : arial; font-size:12pt">'+humanReadableText+'</span><br />';
      else
        humanSpan='<span style='+textStyle+'>'+humanReadableText+'</span><br />';
    }
    result=result+humanSpan;
  }

  for (x = 0; x < encodedData.length; x++)
  {
    var brush;
    if (swing == 0)
      brush = backColor;
    else
      brush = foreColor;

    if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 't')
    {
      if (mode=="html")
        result=result
          +'<span style="border-left:'
          +barWidth
          +units
          +' solid ' 
          +brush
          +';height:'
          +height
          +units+';display:inline-block;"></span>';
      incrementWidth = incrementWidth + barWidth;
    }
    else if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 'w')
    {
      if (mode=="html")
        result=result
          +'<span style="border-left :'
          +thickWidth
          +units+' solid ' 
          +brush
          +';height:'
          +height
          +units+';display:inline-block;"></span>';
      incrementWidth = incrementWidth + thickWidth;
    }

    if (swing == 0)
      swing = 1;
    else
      swing = 0;
  }

  if (mode=="html")
  {
    var humanSpan="";
    if (humanReadable=='yes' && textLocation=='bottom')
    {
      if (textStyle=='')
        humanSpan='<br /><span style="font-family : arial; font-size:12pt">'+humanReadableText+'</span>';
      else
        humanSpan='<br /><span style='+textStyle+'>'+humanReadableText+'</span>';
    }
    result=result+humanSpan+"</div>";
  }
  return result;    
}

function EncodeCode39(data,checkDigit)
{
  var fontOutput = ConnectCode_Encode_Code39(data,checkDigit);
  var output = "";
  var pattern = "";
  for (x = 0; x < fontOutput.length; x++)
  {
    switch (fontOutput.substr(x,1))
        {
      case '1':
        pattern = "wttwttttwt";
        break;
      case '2':
        pattern = "ttwwttttwt";
        break;
      case '3':
        pattern = "wtwwtttttt";
        break;
      case '4':
        pattern = "tttwwtttwt";
        break;
      case '5':
        pattern = "wttwwttttt";
        break;
      case '6':
        pattern = "ttwwwttttt";
        break;
      case '7':
        pattern = "tttwttwtwt";
        break;
      case '8':
        pattern = "wttwttwttt";
        break;
      case '9':
        pattern = "ttwwttwttt";
        break;
      case '0':
        pattern = "tttwwtwttt";
        break;
      case 'A':
        pattern = "wttttwttwt";
        break;
      case 'B':
        pattern = "ttwttwttwt";
        break;
      case 'C':
        pattern = "wtwttwtttt";
        break;
      case 'D':
        pattern = "ttttwwttwt";
        break;
      case 'E':
        pattern = "wtttwwtttt";
        break;
      case 'F':
        pattern = "ttwtwwtttt";
        break;
      case 'G':
        pattern = "tttttwwtwt";
        break;
      case 'H':
        pattern = "wttttwwttt";
        break;
      case 'I':
        pattern = "ttwttwwttt";
        break;
      case 'J':
        pattern = "ttttwwwttt";
        break;
      case 'K':
        pattern = "wttttttwwt";
        break;
      case 'L':
        pattern = "ttwttttwwt";
        break;
      case 'M':
        pattern = "wtwttttwtt";
        break;
      case 'N':
        pattern = "ttttwttwwt";
        break;
      case 'O':
        pattern = "wtttwttwtt";
        break;
      case 'P':
        pattern = "ttwtwttwtt";
        break;
      case 'Q':
        pattern = "ttttttwwwt";
        break;
      case 'R':
        pattern = "wtttttwwtt";
        break;
      case 'S':
        pattern = "ttwtttwwtt";
        break;
      case 'T':
        pattern = "ttttwtwwtt";
        break;
      case 'U':
        pattern = "wwttttttwt";
        break;
      case 'V':
        pattern = "twwtttttwt";
        break;
      case 'W':
        pattern = "wwwttttttt";
        break;
      case 'X':
        pattern = "twttwtttwt";
        break;
      case 'Y':
        pattern = "wwttwttttt";
        break;
      case 'Z':
        pattern = "twwtwttttt";
        break;
      case '-':
        pattern = "twttttwtwt";
        break;
      case '.':
        pattern = "wwttttwttt";
        break;
      case ' ':
        pattern = "twwtttwttt";
        break;
      case '*':
        pattern = "twttwtwttt";
        break;
      case '$':
        pattern = "twtwtwtttt";
        break;
      case '/':
        pattern = "twtwtttwtt";
        break;
      case '+':
        pattern = "twtttwtwtt";
        break;
      case '%':
        pattern = "tttwtwtwtt";
        break;
      default : break;
    }
    output=output+pattern;
  }
  return output;
}

function ConnectCode_Encode_Code39(data,checkDigit)
{
  var Result="";
  var cd="";
  var filtereddata="";
  filtereddata = filterInput(data);
  var filteredlength = filtereddata.length;
  if (checkDigit==1)
  {
    if (filteredlength > 254)
    {
      filtereddata = filtereddata.substr(0,254);
    }
    cd = generateCheckDigit(filtereddata);
  }
  else
  {
    if (filteredlength > 255)
    {
      filtereddata = filtereddata.substr(0,255);
    }
  }
  Result = "*" + filtereddata+cd+"*";
  Result=html_decode(html_escape(Result));  
  return Result;
}

function getCode39Character(inputdecimal) {
  var CODE39MAP=new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
                          "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                          "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
                          "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","-","."," ","$",
                          "/","+","%");
  return CODE39MAP[inputdecimal];
}

function getCode39Value(inputchar) {
  var CODE39MAP=new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
                          "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                          "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
                          "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","-","."," ","$",
                          "/","+","%");
  var RVal=-1;
  for (i=0;i<43;i++)
  {
    if (inputchar==CODE39MAP[i])
    {
      RVal=i;
    }
  }
  return RVal;
}

function filterInput(data)
{
  var Result="";
  var datalength=data.length;
  for (x=0;x<datalength;x++)
  {
    if (getCode39Value(data.substr(x,1)) != -1)
    {
      Result = Result + data.substr(x,1);
    }
  }
  return Result;
}

function generateCheckDigit(data)
{
  var Result="";
  var datalength=data.length;
  var sumValue=0;
  for (x=0;x<datalength;x++)
  {
    sumValue=sumValue+getCode39Value(data.substr(x,1));
  }
  sumValue=sumValue % 43;
  return getCode39Character(sumValue);
}

function html_escape(data)
{
  var Result="";
  for (x=0;x<data.length;x++)
  {
    Result=Result+"&#"+data.charCodeAt(x).toString()+";";
  }
  return Result;
}

function html_decode(str) {
  var ta=document.createElement("textarea");
  ta.innerHTML=str.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
  return ta.value;
}
```

Comment: Is it `checkDigit` going to have an extra letter at the end every time? I am not sure where your `checkDigit` param coming from, but you can `checkDigit = checkDigit.slice(0, -1);` before you call functions.

Comment: The check digit IS the extra letter at the end.